# How to use Firebase correct in for-loops?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to draw things in a canvas but therefor I have to get data for position ect. out of my Firebase-database. To be sure that all things will be drawed I have created a for-loop:

```
  function updatePolice() {
for (var pn=policeNum; pn>0; pn--) {
policeRef.startAt(pn).endAt(pn)
    .once('value', function(snapshot) {
    var readData = snapshot.val();
    var key = snapshot.key();
console.log('Key is nu:', key)
 console.log('X is nu:', readData);
 console.log('Y is nu:', readData.Y);
    });
}
```

But when I run this I get errors in chrome that data can´t be read (see picture)
[Errors in console][1]
    [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUj0M.png

I write this in firebase:

```
 var policeRef = new Firebase("https://webgame.firebaseio.com/police");
function newPolice() {
    policeNum=policeNum+1;
policeRef.child(policeNum).set({
  Nr: policeNum,
  X: policeX,
  Y: policeY
});
updatePolice();
}
```

For the structure of my database, see JSON: (webgame is the database-name. This is the most important part of the JSON)

```
{
  "police" : [ null, {
    "Nr" : 1,
    "X" : 8,
    "Y" : 8
  }, {
    "Nr" : 2,
    "X" : 8,
    "Y" : 8
  },
```

So has anyone an idea why it can´t be read, I think it is caused by the for-loop but maybe you know more. Every answer is welcome, thank you.

Comment: You've included a link to a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export button in your Firebase database. Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: Ok, here is my JSON: http://pastebin.com/G1xprbSE or I will put here a short version of it (it is very long, but the most is the same, it goes about the opper lines.                                                                                      `{
  "police" : [ null, {
    "Nr" : 1,
    "X" : 8,
    "Y" : 8
  }, {
    "Nr" : 2,
    "X" : 8,
    "Y" : 8
  },`......ect